# QML fill width of parent element

Tags: qt, qml

I have a problem, which can be seen on the attached screenshot

[image]

There is ApplicationWindow, which has header and ListView which is used in horizontal layout. Each item of list should be one page of application. Unfortunatelly, the width of base page is not set correctly to fill width of its parent (white background, not the grey one).

Here is the code of main page, it should load Login page - it is shown on the image.

```
ApplicationWindow {
id: root_window
title: Style.applicationName
visible: true
color: "white"
width: Style.windowWidth
height: Style.windowHeight    

ColumnLayout {
    id: root_layout
    spacing: 0
    width: root_window.width
    height: root_window.height

    SmonHeader {
        id: smon_user_app_header
        height: Style.headerHeight
        anchors.top: parent.top
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("Main width: " + width);
    }

    ListView {
        id: navigation

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        interactive: true // disable manual pageChange

        snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem // while moving to right, finish move
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange // mouse gesture make currentIndex change
        highlightMoveDuration: 400 // speed up pages change (swap)

        model: ObjectModel {
            /* First page with login capabilities */
            Login {
                id: login_module
                width: root_layout.width
                height: root_layout.height
            }
        }
    }
}

/* Private function definition*/
function init_database()
{
    var database = Storage.LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync(Style.databaseName, Style.databaseVersion, Style.databaseDescr, Style.databaseSize);
    smonDatabase.startDatabase(Style.databaseName);
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    init_database();
}
}
```

Here is base of Login page

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

import "../"
import "./common"

Rectangle {
id: login_page
// why parent.width is not set ?
anchors.fill: parent
//width: parent.width
//Layout.fillWidth: true

property string credentials_title: qsTr("Přístupové údaje")
property string available_devices: qsTr("Dostupné servery")
property string identity_title: qsTr("Identita")
property string password_title: qsTr("Heslo")
property string domain_title: qsTr("Doména")
property string infoLine_title: qsTr("Zapamatovat přihlašovací údaje")
property string username_title: qsTr("Jméno");

Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log("Login width: " + login_page.width);
    control.cancelEnabled = false
}

ColumnLayout{
    id: navigation
    spacing: Style.spacing
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.leftMargin: Style.defaultAnchors
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    anchors.fill: parent
    width: parent.width

    Text {
        id: title
        //anchors.top: parent.top
        //anchors.left: parent.left
        font.pointSize: Style.fontSizeHeading

        text: credentials_title
    }

    ColumnLayout{
        id: navigationLogin
        spacing: Style.spacing
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: Style.defaultAnchors
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.bottomMargin: Style.bottomMargin
        width: (parent.width - 4*Style.defaultAnchors)

        GridLayout {
            id: input_login
            rowSpacing: Style.denseSpacing
            columns: 2
            columnSpacing: Style.spacing
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: Style.defaultAnchors
            width: 200

            Text {
                id: user_name
                font.pointSize: Style.fontSizeSubHeading

                text: username_title
            }

            SmonComboBox {
                id: user
                width: parent.width

                value: smonRole.user
                object: smonRole
                prop: "user"
                isEditable: true
                dataModel: smonRole.userData
                selectedIndex: smonRole.userNameSelected
            }

            Text {
                id: password_name
                font.pointSize: Style.fontSizeSubHeading

                text: password_title
            }

            SmonTextField {
                id: password
                width: parent.width
                type: "password"

                object: smonRole
                prop: "pass"
                value: smonRole.pass

                onEnterPressed: {
                    user.enabled = false
                    password.enabled = false
                    //control.okEnabled = false
                    control.okEnabled = false
                    control.cancelEnabled = true

                    smonRole.save();
                    smonCommunication.connect();
                }

                onValueChanged: {
                    if(password.value !== "")
                    {
                        control.okEnabled = true
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        control.okEnabled = false
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        ColumnLayout {
            id: scanning
            spacing: Style.denseSpacing
            anchors.left: parent.left
            //Layout.fillWidth: true



            RowLayout {
                id: slider_component

                Text {
                    id: scanningHeader
                    font.pointSize: Style.fontSizeSubHeading

                    text: qsTr("Perioda vyhledávání zařízení");
                }

                Text {
                    id: value
                    font.pointSize: Style.fontSizeInfo
                    anchors.left: scanningHeader.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: Style.defaultAnchors
                    width: 30

                    text: slider.value
                }
            }

            Slider {
                id: slider
                minimumValue: 2
                maximumValue: 30
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                stepSize: 1

                value: smonCommunication.scanPeriod

                onValueChanged: {
                    smonCommunication.scanPeriod = slider.value;
                }
            }
        }

        SmonControlPanel {
            id: control
            width: parent.width
            okEnabled: smonRole.user != "" && smonRole.pass != ""
            okVisible: true
            cancelVisible: true

            onSignalOk: {
                // hide content
                user.enabled = false
                password.enabled = false
                control.okEnabled = false
                control.cancelEnabled = true

                smonRole.save();
                smonCommunication.connect();
            }

            onSignalCancel: {
                // show content again
                password.enabled = true
                user.enabled = true
                //domain.enabled = true
                control.cancelEnabled = false
                control.okEnabled = true

                //smonConnection.logout();
                smonCommunication.disconnect();
                smonRole.disconnected();
            }
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: favourite
        font.pointSize: Style.fontSizeHeading

        text: available_devices
    }

    ListView{
        id: servers
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        width: parent.width

        model: smonCommunication.devicesList

        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: serverList
            height: 80
            width: parent.width

            ColumnLayout{
                Text {
                    id: serverName
                    text: modelData.bluetooth_name
                }

                Text {
                    id: rssi
                    text: modelData.bluetooth_rssi
                }
            }

            MouseArea {
                id: bt_device
                anchors.fill: parent

                onClicked: {
                    if(smonCommunication.btCanConnect === true)
                        smonCommunication.connect(index);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

MessageDialog {
    id: errorDialog
    standardButtons: StandardButton.Cancel | StandardButton.OK
    visible: false;

    informativeText: smonCommunication.errorMessage

    onInformativeTextChanged: {
        errorDialog.visible = true;
    }
}
```

}

Is there problem on the main page or on the page which is loaded ? Thanks for help...

Comment: This is more code than you should expect a person willing to help you would be willing to read. It is best to produce a minimal example illustrating your problem, this will increase the chances to get help. Keep in mind when using layouts, it is the layout which manages the object size, so you shouldn't be using width/height but the attached layout properties.

Comment: Your main page specifies a column layout with two children but one of the is made as big as the layout is in full.
So either it is too big or you want something other than a column layout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem lies with the `anchors.fill: parent` bit in your `ObjectModel`.

The `parent` here, is not the ListView, but the `ListView`'s [`contentItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#contentItem-prop), which happens to have an implicit width of 100px.

In your minimal example, something like this should work:

```
model: ObjectModel {
    /* First page with login capabilities */
    Rectangle{
        id: one
        //anchors.fill: parent <- parent is not navigation
        width: navigation.width
        height: 50
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

Generally speaking, you should not use the `parent` property in your delegates.

Answer (score 2):

So, after answers from ddriver and Kevin Krammer (thanks) I made a minimal working example.

I stopped using ColumnLayout, and set everything as best as I can.

Here is the code

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQml.Models 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
id: root_window
title: "Hello world"
visible: true
color: "white"
width: 480
height: 520

Rectangle {
    id: smon_user_app_header
    height: 50
    color: "blue"
    width: parent.width
}

ListView {
    id: navigation

    orientation: ListView.Horizontal
    interactive: true // disable manual pageChange

    snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem // while moving to right, finish move
    highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange // mouse gesture make currentIndex change
    highlightMoveDuration: 400 // speed up pages change (swap)

    anchors.top: smon_user_app_header.bottom
    anchors.bottom: root_window.bottom

    width: parent.width
    height: 400

    model: ObjectModel {
        /* First page with login capabilities */
        Rectangle{
            id: one
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "red"
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is how it looks

[image]